# Difference between "WHERE " and "IN" in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

What is difference between:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE cat_id IN (1, 2, 6, 8);
```

and create a loop:

```
 foreach($cat as $key => $value){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE cat_id = $value['id'];
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first example is far more efficient because only 1 sql query is run. The second example has x amount of queries, and is far slower.

I would say that you should **never** do it the second way and always the first way.

Comment: Now for a real question :-) Compare `x IN (y, z, q)` with `x = y OR x = z OR x = q` including differences in NULL handling, if any.

Comment: @meder , how can I tell this to my patron that "your query is wrong" :))

Comment: @TheNone Tell him that his query has to be run `count($cat)` time, while the other has to be run just once. This means that any overhead for a single query (and there _is_ overhead, like communicating through the underlying socket) is multiplied by `count($cat)`, even though it doesn't need to. Also, using the `IN` operator lets the database engine optimize its query plan, knowing that it needs to find several specific entries; you can't do that if you execute several individual queries.

Comment: @zneak, I know that first query in correct and I have used "IN". But I know that he will change my query to second one tomorrow :)).

Comment: @TheNone Then what are you asking for? I thought you were looking for arguments to support your point.

Comment: @pst: Don't hijack questions -- post your own, assuming it's not a duplicate

Comment: @TheNone: SQL is SET based; procedural programming in SQL is a last-ditch alternative, and it's a common misconception that SQL is procedural.

Answer (score 2):

The first example runs only 1 query, while the second runs N queries.

Oh yeah, **never** do it the second way.

Comment: Now for a real question :-) Compare `x IN (y, z, q)` with `x = y OR x = z OR x = q` including differences in NULL handling, if any.

Comment: @zneak LOL, my bad. I meant the second.

Answer (score 0):

I think just for some circumstances, when you want to extract data from DB in **exact order** of input ids, you might want to use the second statement.

In this case, when you use the first query, the result might not in the order of input ids (1,2,6,8) if these ids are not in this order in DB. The first id that matches the DB will return result.

Comment: There's no ORDER BY so I doubt that would be useful.  My comment was going to be (on top of "why run a query x times") "How would you produce a sorted results set doing it the second way".

Comment: I just for one of my cases, I need to do the second way or I am just stupid. I have an array of user_id which looks like [10,2,5,1,4] and I need to get user properties for these guys. I do it the second way and get exactly what I want.

Of course, you can do it by some other method like sort the input id array and then get it by using **IN** with **ORDER BY**. But as I said, I found in some circumstances, the second way is somewhat useful.